# remove required administrator privileges from 7Zip command line, when you run the file

Tags: command-line, privileges, 7zip, administrator

I created a file with 7Zip command line.

```
..\7zr a archive.7z c:\1\temp -r
copy /b ..\7zS.sfx + config.txt + archive.7z run.exe
```

config.txt

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
RunProgram="temp\autorun.exe"
InstallPath="%temp%\\MyApp"
Progress="no"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

The resulting EXE file required administrator privileges. How can you create a file without administrator privileges. none of the files in the compressed folder need administrator privileges.

Comment: possible duplicate of [7zip Self Extracting Archive (SFX) without administrator privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923346/7zip-self-extracting-archive-sfx-without-administrator-privileges)